# Pyplot pcolormesh confused when alpha not 1

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having some difficulty with pyplot's awesome drawing abilities. I have selected my very own colormap

```
n = 6
map = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Dark2')
cmap = colors.ListedColormap([(0,0,0,0)] + [[map(i * 1.0 / n)[j] for j in range(3)] + [0.2] for i in range(1, n + 1)])
```

This is basically just the Dark2 colormap, discretized to n (in my case 6) values with the zero value mapping to pure white. The main difference, however, is that the `alpha` values for my custom colormap are set to `0.2`, not `1` as is default.

The problem is that when I plot something using this, like

```
plt.pcolormesh(np.random.rand(10,10), cmap = cmapInv)
```

the result is something like this:

[image: Result]

This looks nice enough, but you can clearly see that around each box, there is a very thin border of the same color as the box but with `alpha` set to `1`.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, the cause of these borders is probably overlap between the boxes.

Is there a way to clean this up?

Comment: Could it be that neighboring boxes just overlap slightly? I don't think there is a border around each box.

Comment: That sounds very likely. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: You could try different backends or different output formats. How do you create the PNG in detail?

Comment: I just saved the output that the method put out (in the window it creates)

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to save the image and then write an image-processing script to erase the overlaps.

Comment: This may be related: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1188

Comment: I remember seeing something else that `pcolormesh` does not play nicely with alpha, but can not track it down.  I think this is worth opening as an issue on github (with this lovely example).

Comment: if this is different that the 1188, if it is the same please add this example to that thread.

Comment: I see. As far as I understand, this is obviously a minor bug in pyplot, so there's nothing more to be done here. If you just post your explanation as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a minor workaround in the meantime, I found you can get the image closer to what you want by messing with the `edgecolor` and `linewidth` attributes. For example, using the following input to `pcolormesh`:

```
    plt.pcolormesh(np.random.rand(10,10), cmap = cmapInv, edgecolor=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.3), linewidth=0.0015625)
```

outputs the following image:

[image]

Comment: Why this particular choice of values edgecolor=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.3), linewidth=0.0015625 ?

Comment: I settled on the values after trial and error. The idea is to use edges to lighten the overlaps between the squares, so I needed white with the appropriate level of transparency to make overlaps match the interiors, and the line width was chosen to be approximately the width of the overlap.