# How can I remove the edges from the hist2d

Tags: matplotlib

I plot the 2D histogram using `hist2d` in `matplotlib`. I want to remove the unwanted black edges. How can I do that? These edges appear when I add `alpha=0.5` to `hist2d`.

[image: hist2d]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678817/pyplot-pcolormesh-confused-when-alpha-not-1, also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100747/changing-facecolor-alpha-value-gives-unwanted-edges-matplotlib-pcolormesh, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092991/white-lines-in-matplotlibs-pcolor